# убрать index.php со средины url и убрать /web/

Tags: php, yii2, apache

Сейчас сайт страница грузиться по такому адресу `http://woolf/index.php/hello`, а как сделать так чтобы грузилось без /index.php/ в средине url?
Файл .htaccess в папке web выклядит так:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

и urlManager в config/web.php тоже раскомментировал.

Comment: Но если следовать тем советам, то они не помогли мне...

Comment: Значит делаешь что-то не так

Comment: Логично, но я решаю эту проблему не первый день и не как не могу решить...Хотя перепробовал массу советов

Comment: `Но если следовать тем советам, то они не помогли мне` - как именно не помогли? ошибки какие-то пишет или что? ты сделал абсолютно всё, что там написано? что написано в urlmanager? куда попадаешь при http://woolf/hello? у тебя windows или linux? Может быть тебе стоит переименовать `woolf` в `woolf.ru` к примеру? Ибо может менеджер парсит урл и твой `woolf` принимает за контроллер)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess должен выглядеть так:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```